Seeing blank value for field in LWC lightning-select tag if the value in field is not from picklist options
I am iterating over a list of Opportunities using template for loop and showing StageName picklist using lightning-select tag as below. picklistOptions are coming from the field based on the RT of the oppty records(all are of same RT here in for loop)
<lightning-select
  name="Status"
  value={opp.StageName}
  options={picklistOptions}
  data-id={opp.Id}
  data-field="StageName"
></lightning-select>

This field is showing correct picklist value if the value is from the picklistOptions, but if the value is not from the picklistOptions, it is showing blank unlike Salesforce which shows the selected value along with other options.
StageName Picklist in Salesforce: (Active option was populated from backend and isn't from picklist values)

﻿StageName picklist in my custom development:(Showing blank instead of 'Active' selected):﻿

How can I show value preselected here?
I'm using below code to get the picklistOptions:
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT })
getobjectInfo(result) {
  if (result.data) {
    const rtis = result.data.recordTypeInfos;
    this.recordTypeId = Object.keys(rtis).find((rti) => rtis[rti].name === 'Lead Opportunity');
  }
};

@wire(getPicklistValues, {
  recordTypeId: '$recordTypeId',
  fieldApiName: STAGENAME_FIELD
})
statusValues;

get picklistOptions() {
    return this.statusValues.data ? this.statusValues.data.values : [];
}


Hi, welcome to SFSE and thanks for your question. There is probably a question as to why you would want to display a value that should not exist, and more fundamentally, how do these values end up in your fields in the first place. You could possibly add any missing options to the picklist dynamically if the pre-populated value doesn't exist, but what is the value in doing this and what other issues may this cause?

Hi @CallumMacErlich, thank you for your response. This is not a Restricted Picklist so some values are inserted from backend which are not in picklist options. I am trying to achieve something like Salesforce here. In the snapshots, the 'Active' value is populated from backend and is visible on Salesforce layout but not visible in my LWC component.
